# Purpose of "originating elements" in Java annotation processing

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Several Java annotation processing methods for creating files, such as [`createResouce(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Filer.html#createResource(javax.tools.JavaFileManager.Location,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,javax.lang.model.element.Element...)), refer to "originating elements":

> `originatingElements` - class or interface or package or module elements causally associated with the creation of this file, may be elided or `null`

Can someone provide more clarity on what this means and in what circumstances I would want to provide an "originating element" when creating a file?

Is this an existing element (such as the element that originally had the annotation being processed) for which I am creating the new file? But then how would the `originatingElements` be used? What difference would it make if I indicate them or not?

Comment: The documentation for the whole interface explains this pretty clearly: "This information may be used in an incremental environment to determine the need to rerun processors or remove generated files. Non-incremental environments may ignore the originating element information."

Comment: Diving into the source, it looks like that is originatingElements is passed, then it will try to make the created resource a sibling of the first element in the array. Specifically when trying to call [JavaFileManager.getFileForOutput](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaFileManager.html#getFileForOutput(javax.tools.JavaFileManager.Location,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,javax.tools.FileObject)) it will try to convert that first element to use as the sibling argument.